# Копирование в React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть ли какие то способы делать глубокое копирование? Может библиотека какая? Я столкнулся с проблемой, что если работаю с иммутабельными данными для пользователя, например state в компонентах или кусочек store в редьюсерах, мне разумеется нужно делать из них копию. Если это например массив чисел, то нет проблем, но если это массив объектов с ссылками на другие объекты, то все становится сложнее. Есть ли универсальное средство для решения таких проблем?

Answer (score 0):

В es6 появился spread оператор ..., он копирует коллекцию (массив, объект).

В редьюсере просто делаем

```
let newState = {...state, myNewVar}

return newState
```

Comment: Это неглубокое копирование

Comment: А какое?  spread оператор добавит в новый объект все свойства старого с любым уровнем вложенности.  Я его всегда использую в редьюсерах и при setSate.  Может быть тогда опишите ваш конкретный кейс?

Comment: Например мне нужно скопировать массив объектов

Answer (score 0):

есть у пакета `lodash` метод `cloneDeep`

Answer (score -1):

Универсальное средство :)

```
const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
```